# Add array on the key of another array in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I'm working in Laravel. I have two arrays, and I want to insert the second array as a value in the first. For example, given

```php
$firstArray = [
    'id' => 1,
    'propery_name' => 'Test Property'
];

$secondArray = [
    'id' => 2,
    'user_name' => 'john'
];
```

, I want to produce an equivalent of

```php
$resultArray = [
    'id' => 1,
    'propery_name' => 'Test Property',
    'userData' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'user_name' => 'john'
    ]
];
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultArray = $firstArray;
$resultArray['userData'] = $secondArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$firstArray = ['id'=>1,'propery_name'=>'Test Property'];
    $secondArray = ['id'=>2,'user_name'=>'john'];

    $resultArray = ['property' => $firstArray, 'userData' => $secondArray];
```

Your newly created array should give you this:

```
    {{  $resultArray['userData']['user_name'] }} = John

    {{  $resultArray['property']['propery_name'] }} = Test Property
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstArray['userData'] = $secondArray;

return $firstArray;

//result

$resultArray = [
    'id' => 1,
    'propery_name' => 'Test Property',
    'userData' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'user_name' => 'john'
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel collection class for this. Push function is best way to add values in array. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-put

In your case,

```
$firstArray = [
    'id' => 1,
    'propery_name' => 'Test Property'
];

$secondArray = [
    'id' => 2,
    'user_name' => 'john'
];
$collection = collect($firstArray);
$collection->put('userData', $secondArray);
$collection->all();
```

Output:

```
 ['id' => 1,
  'propery_name' => 'Test Property',
  'userData' => [
      'id' => 2,
      'user_name' => 'john'
     ]
 ];
```